# Is there pure cumulative Postgresql wait statistic inside database?

Tags: postgresql, statistics, wait

I'd like receive waits statistics like in MS SQL **sys.dm_os_wait_stats ** or Oracle **V$SYSTEM_EVENT**

Postgresql doc recommends only look **pg_stat_activity** using snapshot like this. But it's not pure cumulative statistics. Is there any other ways to see all cumulative waits time\count?

```
while true
do
        psql -h server -U postgres --no-align --csv --tuples-only -c "select now() as timestamp, wait_event_type, wait_event, count(*) as count from pg_stat_activity where state='active' group by wait_event_type, wait_event;"
        sleep 3
done
```

I searched postrgesql doc and google

Comment: No, there is no such way.

Comment: Is there better workarounds instead making snapshot for pg_stat_activity?

Comment: I am pretty sure SQL Server samples those wait events as well. If you don't want to implement the sampling yourself, you can use e.g. [pg_wait_sampling](https://github.com/postgrespro/pg_wait_sampling)

Comment: @a-horse-with-no-name Thanks for tool. I make highload test and I see that dbms is not quite quik :) so manual\third party sampling will be not quik too :(